# VBA problem adding value with getpivotdate

Tags: excel, vba

I have a piece of a macro that will extract data from a table, but I would like to add a sumif result to it. however, I get an error "Application definied or object - definied error". the same function get pivot data works only the problem is + Application.

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Set pt = wbMe.Sheets("INFO").PivotTables("Tabela przestawna1")
wbMe.Sheets("Tabela_COREP").Range("J5") = pt.GetPivotData("Suma z EXP_PIERWOTNA", "RODZAJ_AKTYWÓW", "Pozostałe aktywa", "CRD_AC", "06", "CRD_CCF", 1, "CRD_RWG", 0).Value + Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(wbMe.Sheets("nostra").Range("A1:A"), "PKO BP S.A.", wbMe.Sheets("nostra").Range("F1:F"))
```

Comment: `A1:A` and `F1:F` are not valid ranges in Excel. Use `A:A` and `F:F`

Comment: amazing thanks !